# linux + how to verify the dynamic ports allocation settings

Tags: linux, port, redhat-enterprise-linux, kernel, sysctl

How to know the range for the allocation of dynamic ports on red hat Linux machine

From Linux we did

```
sysctl -a | egrep "net.inet.ip.portrange.first|net.inet.ip.portrange.last"
```

but those parameters are not in kernel configuration

is that parameters are equivalent to the setting in file - `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_port_range` ?

```
more /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_port_range
1024    65535
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameter you search for is `net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range` and the syntax in `sysctl` is:

```
net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range = 1024    65535
```

So your `grep` should be:

```
sysctl -a | egrep "net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range"
```

P.S. I did not found `net.inet.ip.portrange.first`, `net.inet.ip.portrange.last` to be valid kernel parameters

Answer (score 0):

I think the parameters you checked are for FreeBSD, not Red Hat. On Red Hat, you should check the range with:

```
sysctl net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range
```

The command will return min and max port numbers. And yes, you can also view the range by checking this file: `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_port_range`

To change the range of dynamic ports on Red Hat, you can use

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range="MIN MAX"
```

Replace the MIN and MAX with the desired new port ranges. Be sure you know what you are doing when changing these. For a permanent change, you need to edit the `/etc/sysctl.conf` file and add this line

```
net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range = MIN MAX
```

Save the file and run `sysctl -p`